# What's the most elegant way to perform the same actions on two different elements in two overlapping scenarios?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two `<p>` elements, $elem1 and $elem2. Collectively, we can call them $elems. I want to make each of their text red in color under the following scenarios:

$elem1 when the screen size is under 600 pixels wide
$elem2 as soon as the page loads (aka, it should turn red instantly and stay red)

Now, I could do something like:

```
$elem2.css('color', 'red');

if (screenSize < 600) {
  $elem1.css('color', 'red');
}
```

Which is manageable, but what if instead of making each element's text red, I wanted to add 20 attributes, plus some on click events and a CSS class. Now the above code has ballooned up to a whole lot of duplicate code.

My question is, how can I elegantly write jQuery/Javascript that encompasses both $elem1 and $elem2's scenarios so that the "add attribute/event/addClass" code is only spelled out once?

I've tried spelling out all the added attributes/events/addClass for each scenario separately, and that does work, but I know it's going to cause maintenance issues in the future when I forget to replace something in one and not the other.

Comment: it's ridiculous. you have to use the media query for that and not javascript code

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an object to `.attr()` to pass multiple attributes and values

https://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributes

Using this, you could have shared keys

```js
const shared = { checked: "checked", "data-id": id }

$elem2.attr(shared);
$elem2.attr({
  // elem2 specific
});

if (screenSize < 600) {
  $elem1.attr(shared);
  $elem1.attr({
    // elem1 specific
  });
}
```

---

For what it's worth, given that you are concerned about code duplication, maintenance and managing presentation change, a declarative/component-based alternative library like React might solve your problems

Comment: I like the simplicity of this answer, and it does answer my original question, though I just updated my question slightly, as I used the word "attributes" in the original but I'm actually needing to also add some on click events and a new CSS class to each element. Is there a similar solution to what you proposed that would enable me to add events/classes as well? Would it make sense for me to write a function that does all these things to each $elem and run it when the conditions of each scenario are met?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you give each element a class name and update css that way? For example say we assign elem1 and elem2 a css class called aCssClassToUpdate. Then do following:

```
const classesToUpdate = document.querySelectorAll('.aCssClassToUpdate');
classesToUpdate.forEach(classToUpdate => {
  classToUpdate.style.color = 'red';
});
```

Comment: I think this is solving a problem other than the one I have. It sounds like this solution would apply a style to all elements with a certain class, but my problem is that I need to apply a whole bunch of attributes, not all of them CSS styles, to two separate elements under two different scenarios.